# How to animate an hover button with :after pseudoclass and jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, button

Someone knows how to make these hover effects with jquery??
https://tympanus.net/Development/CreativeButtons/

thanks, I'm trying to learn, I don't need the sheet to buy or download

I've just analized it and it appears that there is an element:

section p button (the p I discovered is a better way to center, very nice)

a class for the button:

.btn

a normal pseudoclass for the basic hover effects:

.btn:hover

an after pseudoclass for the jquery animations:

.btn:after

what I don't understand is how to animate .btn:after using jquery

here I have a reference sheet that I'm doing for myself where you can try (the css is not dry because it is a reference sheet and in a future I can use it to look to a specific object, class to reuse or modify
https://codepen.io/Heavybrush/pen/bWgXpx

I tryed to use

```
$(".btn2").hover(
  function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({height: "80px"},300);
  },
  function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({height: "0"},300);
  }
);
```

changing this with ".btn2:after" but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems js/jq cannot get pseudo element. so u cannot animate a pseudo element like a normal element.

u should animate pseudo element in css like

```
.btn::after{
}

.btn:hover::after{
}
```

if the animation is dynamically generate. u can create it like

```
var style = document.createElement('style');
style.innerText = '...animation style';
document.head.append(style);
```

Comment: you may be right, but I tryed also this variant and it doesn't work, with both :after and ::after

what I'm trying to do is to study these animations and try to redo to understand, but something seems to be animated with jquery, some of these animations I think I cannot make with css 

try to get a look to the link attached and you can see that

Comment: ok I found 

.btn-1b:hover:after, .btn-1b:active:after {
    height: 100%;
}

you were right, but it doesn't work to me, I don't understand why